improving model accuracy through hyperparameter tuning
I have developed a RandomForestClassifier model using scikit-learn for a classification task. The model's current accuracy is lower than desired. I believe that adjusting the hyperparameters, such as n_estimators and max_depth, could enhance performance, but I need guidance on the most efficient method for hyperparameter tuning in scikit-learn.

Take a look at grid search in scikit-learn: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html. You can specify a list of values to search for each parameter of interest, and it will train models with all possible combinations.
